Cordova / Android: sim permission denied
I'm trying to retrieve sim info from my phone with Cordova / Android but I get a permission denied despite having the plug-in correctly installed and config.xml with the right permissions.
I have the following plug-ins installed:
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.1.5 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-battery-status 2.0.3 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-device 3.0.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 8.1.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 5.0.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 6.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 3.0.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-network-signal-strength 1.0.0 "network-signal-strength"
cordova-plugin-rssi 1.2.0 "RSSI"
cordova-plugin-sim 1.3.3 "SIM"
org.apache.cordova.signal-strength 1.0.0 "Signal"

In my config.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

and then in my JS:
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() 
    {
       checkPermissions();
}

    function checkPermissions() {
        var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
        var permissionsList = [
            permissions.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            permissions.READ_SMS,
            permissions.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS
        ];

        permissions.checkPermission(permissionsList[0], function(status) {
            if (status.hasPermission) {
                console.log("Permissions already granted");
                getSimInfo();
                getBatteryStatus();
            } else {
                console.log("Permissions not granted, requesting permissions");
                permissions.requestPermissions(permissionsList, function(status) {
                    if (status.hasPermission) {
                        console.log("Permissions granted after request");
                        getSimInfo();
                        getBatteryStatus();
                    } else {
                        console.error("Permissions denied");
                    }
                }, function(error) {
                    console.error("Permission request error:", error);
                });
            }
        }, function(error) {
            console.error("Permission check error:", error);
        });
    }

   function getSimInfo() {
        if (window.plugins && window.plugins.sim) {
            window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(function(result) {
                console.log('Carrier: ' + result.carrierName);
                document.getElementById('carrier').innerText = result.carrierName;
            }, function(error) {
                console.error('Error getting SIM info:', error);
            });
        } else {
            console.error('SIM plugin not available.');
        }
    }

When launching the app, I get the usual permission screens for phone calls and sms, I accept them but when looking in the browser console, I get the output of  console.error("Permissions denied");
It looks like I'm still missing something but I don't know what.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

You should use https://github.com/EYALIN/community-cordova-plugin-sim which is maintained
